# How well were the games in LoZ: Collector's Edition emulated?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube, legend-of-zelda-series, zelda-collectors-edition

The Gamecube game, Legend of Zelda: Collector's Edition included four games (The Legend of Zelda, Zelda II: The Adventure of Link, Ocarina of Time, Majora's Mask) that weren't ported but are emulated on the disc.

Are there are any known problems with this emulation? Are the games slow or glitchy in any way as a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NES titles run just fine. There are no worries there.

The N64 titles run mostly fine. Sometimes they slow down and "lag" a bit. Get a bit choppy, but run surprisingly well for being emulated on the console that is next gen to it.

Played all the way through Ocarina of Time with no problems. Played all the way through Majora's Mask with only 1 freeze. Both were choppy in parts, but overall very playable experience for me.

Comment: Man, the freezing on Majora's Mask is kind of a downer... I just ordered this game off of eBay a few days ago because I wanted to play MM on my Gamecube (if I was worried about OoT, I could get Master Quest)

Comment: I played through all four games on the collector's edition disk and didn't experience any crashes. There was a bit of lag in Ocarina of Time and Majora's Mask during certain actions (particularly bomb explosions or jump attacks that hit many times), but it was identical to the lag in the original N64 versions.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't personally played it, but one of my friends told me this:
Zelda 1 and 2 are OK.
Ocarina of Time had a few crashes.
Majora's Mask has nasty freezing bugs and is virtually unplayable.

Comment: I did entire 3-heart runs of Ocarina of Time and Majora's Mask without any crashes. It sounds like your friend's disk was damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt have any problems with OoT - only that the sound when you picked up a heart was slightly distorted.

MM can crash, which is really bad considering it's saving system.  I suggest waiting for MM 3DS remake or getting the VC version on the Wii.  (I assume the big problems have been fixed for that version).